# Get selected Texbox value in watin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, watin

Is it possible to get selected `TextBox` using `Watin browser`.

Example:

Like in webbrowser Control we can put code behind mouse click event and get the mouse position etc.

Can we do the same here ? If not can we atleast get the selected textbox value when button presses? So i click a TextBox on the browser and i open my winform App and press a button it should automatically get the value of text field. I know we can get it by name or id as below:

```
string phone = fx.Frames[0].TextField(Find.ById("testPhone")).GetValue("value").ToString();
```

But can we do something like:

```
string phone = fx.Frames[0].SelectedTextField.GetValue("value")
```

Comment: I suppose I am a bit confused by your question... are you trying to get the textbox itself or the text within it?

Comment: @Brian I want to get the value of the textbox.So i want it to by dynamic so i click any textbox on the page . And then i click the button on my app and it gets the value.

Comment: I still don't completely understand _why_ you to do it this way?  It's seems you are trying to make your life more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to try, although it will be a bit convoluted.

A) In the WinForm app tie the button click to a call to a WatiN procedure.

B) In the WatiN procedure

- Attach to the open IE browser
- Have a javascript method that finds the Textbox that has focus and gets the value of that textbox. Another approach would be to use WatiN to get all the textfields then loop through them all looking to see which has focus, and get the value that way.
- Return the text value as the return value to the WinForm app.

In theory, I believe all this to be possible though I have no specific experience tying a WinForm app to call a WatiN procedure.

Comment: Ah yes focus is the word i was looking for , perfect to what i need i can just loop on text boxes and get the one in focus.